# How can I specify the exchange source in react trading view widget?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to customize the trading view widget. Like I need to specify the exchange, I need that I get only the Bittrex exchange data in my trading view widget but by default it is giving the data of many exchanges.

Comment: Hello Haider. Could you please post some basic code examples?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.